# Продление жизни локального объекта

Tags: c++

Возможно ли продлить жизнь локального объекта без копирования. Например, дано:

```
string& foo1()
{
    string tmp("hello");
    return tmp;
}
string foo2()
{
    string tmp("hello");
    return tmp;
}
string foo3()
{
    string&& r1 = foo1(); // ошибка.
    string&& r2 = foo2(); // объект будет жить в пределах этих скобок.
}
```

Если я правильно понял, то в данном участке `string&& r2 = foo2(); // объект будет жить в пределах этих скобок` произойдет копирование локального объекта `tmp` из функции `foo2()`. Возможно ли как-нибудь обойтись без копирования при помощи rvalue ссылок или еще чего-нибудь?

Comment: У вас локальный объект будет лежать на стеке. При выходе из функции стек очистится в любом случае и эта память станет невалидная. Вы можете расположить объекты в динамической памяти и возвращать указатель.

Comment: Тогда зачем говорят про продление жизни объекта, если в итоге это просто сводится к его копированию? Или же "продление жизни объекта" является другим случаем?

Comment: Я плохо разбираюсь в C++, он для меня сложный. Пусть кто-нибудь другой ответит. Я так понимаю, продление жизни это о другом. Потому что стек так работает, если вы туда что-то поместили, то после выхода из функции оно очистится. Вы можете создать объект до вызова функции, передать его по ссылке или указателю и что-то туда записать.

Comment: Просто возвращайте по значению, и не используйте rvalue-ссылку: `string r2 = foo2();` По хорошему, компилятор должен догадаться сделать NRVO, и обойтись без копий/перемещений. Даже если не догадается, одно перемещение - разве много?

Comment: А возвращение локального объекта как для lvalue ref, так и для rvalue ref всегда некорректно?

Comment: *зачем говорят про продление жизни объекта* - кто говорит? где? в каком контексте?

Comment: Есть еще RVO/copy elision.

Comment: "Тогда зачем говорят про продление жизни объекта, если в итоге это просто сводится к его копированию? " - копирование - это один из способов продления жизни объекта, особенно, если у него нет коструктора/оператора перемещения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Продление жизни объекта может производиться только для временных объектов и только в пределах области видимости их появления. В выражении `string && r2{foo2()};` как раз появляется анонимный временный объект, создаваемый функцией `foo2` и его жизнь будет продлена пока `r2` не покинет область видимости. То же произойдет и при связывании временного объекта с lvalue ссылкой на const объект `string const & r3{foo2()};`. Связывание временного объекта с lvalue ссылкой на не const объект запрещено.

Функция `foo1` просто возвращает невалидную ссылку на локальный объект, вышедший из области видимости. Возврат ссылки на локальную (не статическую) переменную - всегда ошибка. Функция `foo2` возвращает временный объект, копирование / перемещение которого компилятор радостно оптимизирует, сразу используя место для размещения объекта, предоставленное функцией `foo3`. Но продления жизни локальных объектов, вышедших из области видимости не происходит ни при каких условиях.